# Geometric interpretation of complex eigenvalues

Tags: matrices

What is the geometric interpretation of complex eigenvalues?
For me it is clear that real eigenvalues of a matrix $A$ are associates to eigenvectors along which the matrix $A$ contracts or expands. Complex eigenvalues are associated intuitively (but not clearly) to me to eigenvectors along which the matrix $A$ rotates the space.

Comment: Do you know about the real Jordan form? That makes clear your intuition. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices

Comment: I know it, but I do not have it geometric interpretation clear.

Comment: I may write an answer later but here is a good geometric description: https://www.math.purdue.edu/~bkrummel/ma265_lecture5_5.pdf

Comment: @Al.G. the link is dead, do you remember the title of the note?

Comment: Sadly not, but there are other resources that explain the same. A quick googling lead me here: https://services.math.duke.edu/~jdr/1617f-1553/materials/11-09-web.pdf, which kinda explains what I was thinking about - a pair of complex eigenvalues means *rotation* by the complex value argument within a particular subspace (in contrast to real eigenvalues, which encode *scaling* of the axes).

Answer (score 5):

If $A$ is real matrix and exists its (not real) eigenvalue $\lambda=a+bi$ and eigenvector $x=v+iw$ ($a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, $v,w$-real vectors), then:

$Ax=\lambda x$, so:

$A(v+iw)=\lambda(v+iw)$

$Av+iAw=av-bw+i(aw+bv)$

So $Av=av-bw$ and $Aw=ax+bw$. You can interpret this result this way: there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and vectors $v,w$ that $A$ transforms $v$ to $av-bw$ and $w$ to $aw+bv$.

Comment: I think you want "A transforms" instead of "a transforms".  Other than that, I really like this.

Comment: I m getting some more of intuition, but I still lacking the geometric clear picture...